# Why putting 0 as a first element of array prevent "for" loop execution. [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, arrays

Consider the following JavaScript code:

```
var words = delIdx = [0, 1, 2, 3];
for(let i=0; delIdx[i]; i++) {
  console.log('DELIDX: ', delIdx[i]);
}

for(let i=0; words[i]; i++) {
  console.log('Word: ', words[i]);
}
```

`words` and `delIdx` are arrays, as you can see the array's first element is set to 0 (zero) and the below two FOR loops are using these arrays to control the execution of the loops. But when 0 is the first element of the loop it doesn't work. It doesn't enter any of the loop at all.

If I change the array's value to `var words = delIdx = [2, 3, 4, 5]` then the loops works perfectly.

Has anybody experienced this issue? Why is it so? Is it a bug in the JavaScript?

I experienced this in Node.js v5.3.0 and FireFox 44.0.2 console.

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: `let i=0; delIdx[i]` in `for`, **0 is falsy value**.

Comment: ^ This - I assume you meant `i < delIdx.length` and `i < words.length`?

Comment: http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/

Comment: for the first time `delIdx[i]` gives `0` which is false thats why its not executing.. better you give `i < delIdx.length`

Comment: Thanks all. I got it now. Its because first element renders 0 in loop control part and it becomes false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are using a `for` loop in javascript, the middle part is supposed to be the predicate:

- if it evaluates to `true`, looping continues
- if it evaluates to `false`, looping stops

Here you are passing it `0`, which evaluates to `false`, so no looping happens.

Answer (score 0):

Because when it evaluates 0 it will return false that's why loop is not working 
but when you remove 0 form array it will return true and the loop works fine 
you can also traverse your array by using this code,

```
var words = delIdx = [0, 1, 2, 3];
for(var i=0; i<delIdx.length; i++) {
  console.log('DELIDX: ', delIdx[i]);
}

for(var i=0; i<words.length; i++) {
  console.log('Word: ', words[i]);
}
```